# Pandas Equivalent of Excel COUNTIFS

Tags: pandas

I've read through some previous questions and am having trouble implementing. Here is my table.

```
Value Bool
abc   TRUE
abc   TRUE
bca   TRUE
bca   FALSE
asd   FALSE
asd   FALSE
```

I want this:

```
Value  Bool  Count
abc    TRUE  2
abc    TRUE  2
bca    TRUE  1
bca    FALSE 1
asd    FALSE 0
asd    FALSE 0
```

For each group of terms in Value, count the number of occurrences of TRUE, which is a boolean in my df.

In Excel you can do COUNTIFS to do this. Can someone please show me the way in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with groupby transform:

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('Value')['Bool'].transform('sum')
print(df)

  Value   Bool  Count
0   abc   True    2.0
1   abc   True    2.0
2   bca   True    1.0
3   bca  False    1.0
4   asd  False    0.0
5   asd  False    0.0
```

Or:

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('Value')['Bool'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
print(df)

  Value   Bool  Count
0   abc   True      2
1   abc   True      2
2   bca   True      1
3   bca  False      1
4   asd  False      0
5   asd  False      0
```